# how to parse tick data with quantmod?

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to generate daily candle bars using quantmod, but what I got is GBPJPY.csv tick data, like

```
Symbol,Time,Bid,Ask 
GBP/JPY,2013-12-29 17:01:06.000,173.319,173.544
GBP/JPY,2013-12-29 17:01:07.000,173.319,173.459
GBP/JPY,2013-12-29 17:01:08.000,173.319,173.459
GBP/JPY,2013-12-29 17:01:08.000,173.319,173.544
```

I want to know how to parse it and generate daily candle bar.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to load the ticks into an xts object; second step is to make bars from that xts object.

I will assume your csv file only contains GBP/JPY data (i.e. the first column is redundant). If not, you just need to do a bit more work to use the first column. (Or, better, pre-process your data using unix tools to give you one file per symbol.)

You also didn't say if you want both bid and ask bars, or just one, or mid. The below code assumes bid, as it is simpler.

```
d=try(read.table(source_fname,sep=',',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F),silent=T)
if(inherits(d,"try-error")){
   print(d);quit() #Or some kind of error-handling
   }
timestamps = as.POSIXct(d$Time)
bids = xts(d$Bid,timestamps)
```

Because we only have one column, making daily bars is easy:

```
to.daily(bids)
```

It gives:

```
            bids.Open bids.High bids.Low bids.Close
 2013-12-29   173.319   173.319  173.319    173.319
```

If you need to do something more complicated (e.g. make OHLC for both bid and ask), this answer shows how to use `period.apply()` to apply a custom function to any sized block of ticks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896834/841830  (that question also shows how you could use `read.zoo()` to read the ticks; it is a wrapper around the `read.table()` function).